# VHDL TB for 3 bit bcd to binary

Tags: vhdl

I've got a problem with my test bench for 3 bit BCD to binary decoder. 
Inputs are fine but output is UUUUUU..... 
No idea how to resolve it. Should I assign output somehow? 
I'm using ISE to simulate code.
I have been trying to apply method I have been using in behavioral model but its not accepting it.

```
    -- TestBench Template 
  LIBRARY ieee;
  USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
  USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
  ENTITY testbench IS
  END testbench;
  ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS 
  COMPONENT bcd_2_bin
    PORT(
         bcd_in_0 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd_in_10 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd_in_100 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bin_out : OUT  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   signal bcd_in_0 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal bcd_in_10 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal bcd_in_100 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal bin_out : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
BEGIN
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: bcd_2_bin PORT MAP (
          bcd_in_0 => bcd_in_0,
          bcd_in_10 => bcd_in_10,
          bcd_in_100 => bcd_in_100,
          bin_out => bin_out
        );
-- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
        bcd_in_0 <= x"0"; bcd_in_10 <= x"1"; bcd_in_100 <= x"2";
        wait for 100 ns;
        bcd_in_0 <= x"9"; bcd_in_10 <= x"9"; bcd_in_100 <= x"9"; 
        wait for 100 ns;
        bcd_in_0 <= x"8"; bcd_in_10 <= x"2"; bcd_in_100 <= x"4"; 
      wait;
   end process;
END;
```

Comment: Look at the signals inside the bcd2bin component. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213174/displaying-signals-in-testbench-from-counter-vhdl/213176#213176

Comment: Check your simulator output. Maybe `bin_2_bcd` has not been found and warning about a black-box instance has been issued.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you're asking someone to help you when the heart of the design is inside a box whose contents can't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your testbench. I checked with the following dummy UUT,

```
ibrary ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity bcd_2_bin is
  port (
         bcd_in_0 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd_in_10 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd_in_100 : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bin_out : OUT  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
       );
end bcd_2_bin;

architecture dummy of bcd_2_bin is
  begin
    bin_out(3 downto 0)  <= bcd_in_0;
    bin_out(7 downto 4)  <= bcd_in_10;
    bin_out(9 downto 8)  <= bcd_in_100(1 downto 0);
end dummy;
```

and simulated your testbench successfully without any changes.

Look inside your UUT source to find the problem. Check also for errors or warnings during compilation.